Can I use notify under current notify in ansible playbook
I need to automate a task by ansible:
It is deploy a package ,if successful then deploy another package ,if successful then resatrt the service.
I think that notify inside notify will solve the issue ,
So is it possible to use notify inside notify?
any other suggestion to deploy my playbook using other way?
Sample logic will be:
Deploy package1
If successful deploy package2
If successful restart the service
Not yet Not yet  Not yet

You do not need notify for this. You can simply do all the steps (deploy, deploy, restart) as ansible tasks. Tasks will stop executing at the first failure:
Quote from the linked docu:

When a task has executed on all target machines, Ansible moves on to the next task. [...] If a task fails on a host, Ansible takes that host out of the rotation for the rest of the playbook.

The reason why you'd use notify is to avoid restarting a service when the playbook hasn't modified its configuration. If I understand your question correctly, you don't need this feature. (Otherwise please clarify.)
